# Is there a more convenient way to stop (or restart) a detached celery beat process?

Tags: systemd, celery

Just to clarify things - I am working on a systemd service file `celerybeat.service` which should take care of the Celery beat. What I am doing at the moment is calling a script which reads `/var/run/celery/celerybeat.pid`, kills process with that PID, and then starts Celery beat process again.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: On a modern system you use systemd, of course.

Comment: I *am* using systemd!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we do is we start celery like this (our celery app is in server.py):

```
python -m server --app=server multi start workername -Q queuename -c 30 --pidfile=celery.pid --beat
```

Which starts a celery beat process with 30 worker processes, and saves the pid in celery.pid.

Then we can call this to cleanly exit:

```
celery multi stop workername --pidfile=celery.pid
```

Comment: I did not know about the `--beat` option. I like it as now I do not need the `celerybeat.service` - all will be controlled by the celery.service.

Comment: me neither. this (http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/celery-periodic-tasks-installation-infinity) describe possible gotcha - "the --beat flag needs to appear after worker, otherwise nothing will happen."

Comment: For future Googlers: the docs for `celery worker --help` states that the `-B` or `--beat` option should be used for development purposes only and that you'd need to start celery beat separately in a production environment. See [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2131) for a sample config file.